# Calculate the non-integer power of matrices

Tags: matrices

We know that the product $A^nA^m = A^{n+m}$, $A$ is a square matrix and $n,m$ are integers.

Is this correct for non-integer $A^{\frac{1}{n}} A^{\frac{1}{m}} = A^{\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{m}}$.

Comment: Is the matrix diagonalizable?

Comment: So $A^{\frac{1}{2}} A^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is  not equal to $A$ pjs36.

Comment: That's not exactly what I meant. If you can diagonalize a matrix, it is computationally easier to raise it to a power--weather it is an integer or a rational number.

Comment: How are you defining fractional powers of your matrix?   There may be many, possibly even infinitely many, matrices $B$ such that $B^n = A$.  Which one do you choose to be $A^{1/n}$?

Comment: Michael McGovern, Is it computationally easier to raise it for a diagonal matrix (it seems that it easier to calculate it)  or for all diagonalizable matrices.

Comment: We don't even have $A^{1/2}A^{1/2}=A$. For instance, let $A$ be the $3\times 3$ identity matrix. Every rotation matrix $R$ through an angle $\pi$ satisfies $R^2=A$, so in a sense each is a square root of $A$. But the product of any two such distinct matrices is not $A$.